# Calculating difference of two values and sorting based on the result with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  game table:
 | id | group_id | user_id | last_update         | bonus |
 | 1  | 4        | 1       | 2017-01-22 00:06:10 |    0  |
 | 2  | 4        | 1       | 2017-01-12 00:11:34 |  300  |
 | 3  | 4        | 1       | 2017-01-02 00:30:44 | -111  |
 | 3  | 4        | 1       | 2017-02-02 00:21:44 | 4330  |
 | 3  | 4        | 6       | 2017-01-02 01:02:27 | 30    |
 | 3  | 4        | 6       | 2017-01-07 11:22:37 | 40    |
 | 3  | 4        | 6       | 2017-03-04 11:22:37 |  0    |
```

I want to calculate bonus of the current date minus the bonus of the first day of the current month for every user of a given group.

The wanted output:

```
| user_id | january (last day bonus - first day bonus) |
| 5       | 1400                                     |
| 19      | 1377                                     |
| 1       | 806                                      |
| 14      | 140                                      |
| 50      | 14                                       |
```

Currently, I'm getting bonuses of the given month (1 query), calculating the difference between the last and first ones. I have 4000 users, so I'm performing 4000 queries to do what I want and it's too slow.

Is it possible to do that with only mysql?

Comment: what does the input data look like?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @vkp I updated my question

Comment: can bonus go down with-in the month, or only up?

Comment: @siloko both ways, I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the "most correct" way would be to use variables or complex subqueries.  However, another way that should work is to use `group_concat()`/`substring_index()`:

```
select user_id, date_format(last_update, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       substring_index(group_concat(bonus order by last_update desc), ',', 1) as last_bonus,
       substring_index(group_concat(bonus order by last_update asc), ',', 1) as first_bonus,
       (substring_index(group_concat(bonus order by last_update desc), ',', 1) -
        substring_index(group_concat(bonus order by last_update asc), ',', 1)
       ) as bonus_diff
from t
group by user_id, yyyymm;
```

Note that this converts the `bonus` to a string -- and then back again to a number for the calculation.  That is why I might call this "quick-and-dirty" or a "hack".  However, it should work and the conversions are safe because the values start out as numbers.

Second, `group_concat()` has a default limit of 1024 bytes.  That should not be a problem for these aggregations -- unless you have hundreds of rows for a user within a month.

Comment: (there are 4000 users)

Comment: With this query I get only one record :/, even when I remove the group by

Comment: @smarber . . . You would get one record without the `group by`.  With the `group by`, you should get one record per user and `yyyymm`.